# VBA-Excel Export data to another workbook based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

Dear knowledgeable coders,

I would like to import data from two different Excel workbooks (read: psychological tests) to a single worksheet in a different workbook (a database). However, in some cases a person takes multiple test and thus I don’t want that data in the first blank row of the database. In that scenario I would like to import the data into a existing row with the other test values.

For example, I have a database with the following columns A (unique identifier), B (Intelligence value 1), C (Intelligence value 2), D (Personality test). Person 1 did an intelligence test and a personality test and those results are stored in two different excel files. Now I would like to aggregate those scores in the database. The results of the personality test are already imported in the database, thus Column A and D are already filled. The code in the intelligence test excel file would thus need to identify if a person 1 already exists in the database, before writing to a new line. If the person does not exist, a new line would have to be created. The code of the intelligence test without this lookup would look something like the below.

I can imagine it works with the help of an If-Else command. Also, the code I provided needs to include a cell that refers to that unique identifier. However, I have too little knowledge for this and I am not able to find an appropriate solution. Could one of you please help me out?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Intelligence1 As String
Dim Intelligence2 As String
Dim mydata As Workbook

Worksheets("Scores").Select
Intelligence1 = Range("D3")
Intelligence2 = Range("D4")

Set mydata = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Database-Concept.xlsx")
Worksheets("aggregate").Select
Worksheets("aggregate").Unprotect Password:="1234"
Worksheets("aggregate").Range("a1").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("aggregate").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("aggregate").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = Intelligence1
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = Intelligence2
End With

Worksheets("aggregate").Protect Password:="1234"
mydata.Save

End Sub
```

*Edit*

*Attached screenshots from two dummy files stripped from all the complexity.*

*[Intelligence form (input)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnXdL.png)*

*[Concept database (output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbcP3.png)*

Comment: I can imagine you have the person name somewhere in the Personality xls, also, do you really need to open it -I see the file is constant-, have you tried to get the desired value with a formula referencing to the other WB?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My thought was that a person gets a unique ID assigned (number/text/combination of both) and that value would entered manually in a cell of the Personality.xlsx and the Intelligence.xlsx. That cell may be used by the code to check if there already is an entry for that person in the database. If that is the case I assume the code  would just write in that particular row. Otherwise, it should create a new entry at the first blank row. I hope this helps? I did not try formula referencing.

Comment: Sorry on my delay, I meant a formula like this ='C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\[Database-Concept.xlsx]aggregate'!$A$1 where $A$1 would be the cell where you are going to set the user.

Comment: I am not sure that I completely understand you, but the difficulty with setting up a formula would be that the files and its content have to be static. However, the personality.xlsx and intelligence.xlsx are designed to be forms that are not saved. The content of the filled out forms for patients should be stored in the database. I imagine (not entirely sure) that this will result in difficulties: the formula would refer to an empty or changed cell value? But as I said I am not that experienced with Excel and VBA. Would it help you if I forwarded you the excel files I have created so far?

Comment: I see, so, is there a cell where you have the name of the patient? The formula helps to obtain the value form a closed workbook, you should try it just for the knowledge of it. OT: an image of the template would be enough, edit your question to include it if possible.

Comment: I have added the images to the original post. Also I included some fake data to make it more easy to understand. The name of the patient is the ID and some cells have been moved since I first wrote the code. Thanks so much for your effort so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Intelligence1 As String
Dim Intelligence2 As String
Dim mydata As Workbook
Dim RangeFoundID As Range
Dim RowCount As Long
Worksheets("Scores").Select
Intelligence1 = Range("D3")
Intelligence2 = Range("D4")

Set mydata = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Database-Concept.xlsx")
Worksheets("aggregate").Select
Worksheets("aggregate").Unprotect Password:="1234"
Worksheets("aggregate").Range("a1").Select


'If the cell is constant like in the image
'note however, if there's a duplicated record it won't be fixed and will only update the first of them.
Set RangeFoundID = Columns(1).Find(Cells(2, 3).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If RangeFoundID Is Nothing Then ' 1. If RangeFoundID Is Nothing
RowCount = Worksheets("aggregate").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
'My suggestion above goes to the last real row, what happens if you let a whole row blank? It would count less than really are RowCount = Worksheets("aggregate").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("aggregate")
.Cells(RowCount, 1).Value = Cells(2, 3).Value
.Cells(RowCount, 2).Value = Intelligence1
.Cells(RowCount, 3) = Intelligence2
End With

Else ' 1. If RangeFoundID Is Nothing

With Worksheets("aggregate").Range(RangeFoundID.Address)
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = Intelligence1
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = Intelligence2
End With
End If ' 1. If RangeFoundID Is Nothing


Worksheets("aggregate").Protect Password:="1234"
mydata.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! However, something seems to be going wrong. `RowCount = Worksheets("aggregate").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1` results in a 438 error during execution. Also, regardless if the ID is already in the table it will write in a new row, like it does not identify the ID correctly. Do you have an idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: The error that I had is that I was missing cells RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1. For the ID, please, debug the code and you will see the logic that I used for it, you will notice why it is failing -hint: it may have to do with the find that is performing-

Comment: Funny story: after an hour of trial and error I got a last idea while I was typing a comment on how I wasn't able to figure it out. And now the code works as expected. Thanks a million! Unfortunately the system does not allow me to vote for your solution...

Comment: It's ok you already accepted as an answer and that is helpful as well, have a great day!